# How can I know the type of a file using Boost.Filesystem?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using Boost but I cannot find complete (or good) documentation about the filesystem library in the installation directory nor the web. The "-ls" example I found has been quite a helper but it's not enough.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: boost documentation is often incomplete. and it gives you the impression that they are talking about the functions, not **how to use them**.

Answer (score 18):

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string filename = "hello.txt";

    string extension = boost::filesystem::extension(filename);

    cout << "filename extension: " << extension << endl;

    return 0;    
}
```

The output is ".txt"

Reminder: Compile with '-lboost_system -lboost_filesystem'

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of how you can fetch extension from files :

```
std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> GetAllFileExtensions()
{
    std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> fileExtensions;
    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator b(boost::filesystem::current_path()), e;
    for (auto i=b; i!=e; ++i)
    {
        boost::filesystem::path fe = i->path().extension();
        std::cout << fe.string() << std::endl;
        fileExtensions.push_back(fe);
    }

    return fileExtensions;
}

std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> fileExtensions = GetAllFileExtensions();
```

This example just takes all files and strips extension from them and shows on standard output, you could modify function GetAllFileExtensions to only look at one file

Answer (score -1):

I don't know which operating system you use, but on the UN*X type systems like GNU/Linux the file extension is merely part of the filename and does make any statement about the file contents.  Usually it is ignored all together and only the MIME type of the file is examined (which is done by file managers like Nautilus).

Using Boost you cannot (?) obtain the MIME type of a file but you can use `libmagic` (which is also used by the `file` utility).  It is a pure C library but the functions and types could easily be wrapped in some RAII classes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <cassert>
#include <magic.h>

int main()
{
  std::string filename{"test.png"};

  // allocate magic cookie
  magic_t magic;
  assert( (magic = magic_open(MAGIC_MIME_TYPE)) != nullptr );

  // load the default magic database (indicated by nullptr)
  assert( magic_load(magic, nullptr) == 0 );

  // compile the default magic database (indicated by nullptr)
  assert( magic_compile(magic, nullptr) == 0 );

  // get description of the filename argument
  char const * mime;
  assert( (mime = magic_file(magic, filename.c_str())) != nullptr );

  std::cout << filename << " has type " << mime << "\n";

  // free magic cookie (BEWARE! this frees "mime")
  magic_close(magic);
}
```

On my system the file `test.png` exists and the program prints

```
test.png has type application/octet-stream
```

Certainly not perfect (I expected `image/png`) but close enough.

Answer (score -1):

You can use libmagic, similar to the previous answer, however you don't need to
compile. libmagic detects almost any file type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <magic.h>

using namespace std;
namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;

class MagicFile {
  magic_t mag;

public:
  MagicFile() {
    mag = magic_open(MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);
    if (mag == nullptr)
      throw runtime_error("Magic error");
    magic_load(mag, NULL);
  }

  ~MagicFile() {
    magic_close(mag);
  }

  string mime(bfs::path p) {
    return magic_file(mag, p.c_str());
  }
};
```

To use the code:

```
cout << "mime type: " << MagicFile().mime("myfile.dat") << endl;
```

Or:

```
MagicFile magic;
cout << "mime type: " << magic.mime("myfile.dat") << endl;
```